# With WAMPServer http://hostname works but not http://www.hostname

Tags: apache, web, wampserver

This is a problem because most browsers and websites assume that I forgot the WWW, and it's required to have it work correctly. I'll show you with the website I currently am having this problem with: [Mario Paint Forums.](http://mariopaintforums.ddns.net) That's the right version of the link, but [when we add www., it 404s.](http://www.mariopaintforums.ddns.net)

See the problem?

Comment: you need to amend your host file called `hosts`, which is on Windows in the folder `~\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Comment: your website is already sub domain of ddns.net. If ddns.net lets you create www.subdomain.ddns.net then you can do that, but I doubt that. On the other hand, I certainly don't think browsers assume that you forget www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to amend your host file called `hosts`, which is on Windows in the folder `~\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Add a line like below

```
<ip address> www.mariopaintforums.ddns.net
```

And you should be good

Comment: Yes if he only wants to visit it from his machine! He clearly wants it to work for the internet in general, not just on his machine, which is all the hosts file does.